# Unable to use downloaded Class File

Tags: math-mode, errors, packages, physics

I've been using LaTeX with TeXnicCenter as my editor for about two years, always typing in \text mode with the {align} option.. so boring, I know. Now I decided to get more professional, and downloaded a cls file available on a physics webpage (I'm a phyisicist). I also installed the MiKTeX. When I try to compile my document into a PDF, TeXnicCenter just generates 11 erros and doesn't load it. What is happening?

Perhaps it is worth saying that the erros in the Output always start with pdflatex>

Comment: you have not given any clue that will allow anyone to help. If `zzzz.cls` is in the same folder as the document and the document has `\documentclass{zzzz}` then it will be loaded. If you get errors show the exact error from the log file in a code block in your question. (latex errors never start `pdflatex>`)

Comment: It turned out to be a lack of necessary packages. I just asked MiKTeX to download everything from a list and it worked. Thanks for trying to help.